# Haskell <- in do notation

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

It's well known that `<-` in `do` blocks are just syntactic sugar for `>>=`, but is `<-` defined anywhere in the Haskell source or is it just syntactic construction that is part of language grammar and thus the parser just replaces every `<-` with appropriate form of `>>=`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Do Expression is part of the Language.

From the Haskell Language Report 2010:

> 3.14 [Do Expression](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14)
>
> ```
> lexp  →   do { stmts }            (do expression)
> stmts →   stmt1 … stmtn exp [;]   (n ≥ 0)  
> stmt  →   exp ;
>       |   pat <- exp ;
>       |   let decls ; 
>       |   ;                       (empty statement)
> ```
>
> A do expression provides a more conventional syntax for
>   monadic programming. It allows an expression such as
>
> ```
>  putStr "x: "    >>  
>  getLine         >>= \l ->     
>  return (words l)
> ```
>
> to be written in a more traditional way as:
>
> ```
>  do putStr "x: "  
>     l <- getLine  
>     return (words l)
> ```
>
> As indicated by the translation of do, variables bound by let have fully polymorphic types while those defined by <- are lambda bound and are thus monomorphic.

see [Do Expression](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) of the Haskell Language Report.